# Can't update existing records in Rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

It appears that everything saves properly on my Rails 4 app (using simple_form) when I create a new event, but when I try to update an existing event (by going to `events/3/edit`), it doesn't save any of the changes.

Here is my console log:

```
Started PATCH "/events/3" for 12.43.117.2 at 2015-06-17 19:28:34 +0000
Started PATCH "/events/3" for 12.43.117.2 at 2015-06-17 19:28:34 +0000
Processing by EventsController#update as HTML
Processing by EventsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tdCaXgxDSLNJg2qcsB91W9No3fJpu7Z7XDxktXGGJ5A=", "event"=>{"event_name"=>"Salute Miami’s Bicycling Heroes: Reception for Kirk Munroe & Wilson Larkins", "location"=>"Coco Plum Woman's Club, 1375 Sunset Road, Miami, FL 33143", "event_date_time(1i)"=>"2015", "event_date_time(2i)"=>"6", "event_date_time(3i)"=>"17", "event_date_time(4i)"=>"12", "event_date_time(5i)"=>"03", "description"=>"Honor Kirk Munroe,\r\nblahbicycblah", "organizer"=>"blah", "category"=>"Community Event"}, "commit"=>"Update Event", "id"=>"3"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tdCaXgxDSLNJg2qcsB91W9No3fJpu7Z7XDxktXGGJ5A=", "event"=>{"event_name"=>"Salute Miami’s Bicycling Heroes: Reception for Kirk Munroe & Wilson Larkins", "location"=>"Coco Plum Woman's Club, 1375 Sunset Road, Miami, FL 33143", "event_date_time(1i)"=>"2015", "event_date_time(2i)"=>"6", "event_date_time(3i)"=>"17", "event_date_time(4i)"=>"12", "event_date_time(5i)"=>"03", "description"=>"Honor Kirk Munroe,\r\nblahbicycblah", "organizer"=>"blah", "category"=>"Community Event"}, "commit"=>"Update Event", "id"=>"3"}
  Rendered events/update.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
  Rendered events/update.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 173ms (Views: 171.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 173ms (Views: 171.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

After this happens, I get a blank update event page with no form fields on it. I then return to the event index and go back to the individual event only to find that it's the way it was originally. Whatever it's doing, it seems to be sending information twice (the original info first and then the updated), but for some reason the updates don't seem to be sticking.

For what it's worth, the `def update` portion of the event controller is empty and i'm using a postgresql database.

Github repo: https://github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration
Test server: https://wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/

Comment: In Rails 4 the default HTTP verb used for updates is now `PATCH` (where it used to be `PUT`). It's primarily a change in semantics and shouldn't cause any issues with data not being saved.

Comment: @neuronaut good to know -- one less thing to worry about! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, based off this (replacing the word `user` with `event`): https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-unsuccessful_edits

`events_controller.rb`:

```
def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if @event.update_attributes(event_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'update'
    end
  end
```

Maybe deleting the `else render 'update'` might avoid the blank "update an event" page that shows up after I do it, but this is more of a back-end feature (users aren't going to have a link to edit these events) and it accepts changes, so i'm content.